# linq count/groupby not working

Tags: linq

I want to group by the categoryid and then do a count on this. But I don't know how to do this. I have tried a couple of ways without success. Here is my latest:

```
public class Count
{
    public int TradersCount { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }       
}


    public IQueryable<Count> CountTradersAttachedToCategories()
    {
        var data = from tc in _db.tblTradersCategories
                   select new Count
                  {

                        Description = tc.tblCategory.description,
                        Id = tc.tblCategory.categoryId,
                        TradersCount = tc.Select(x => x.categoryid).GroupBy().Count()

                   };

        return data;
    }
```

- tblTradersCategories joins both
  tblTraders/tblCategories
- A single trader can have many categories
- A single category can have many traders

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = from tc in _db.tblTradersCategories
           group tc by new { tc.tblCategory.categoryId,
                             tc.tblCategory.description } into g
           select new { Count = g.Count(),
                        Id = g.Key.categoryId,
                        Description = g.Key.description };
```

If you want that in your `Count` class you *may* need to use AsEnumerable() to perform the conversion in process:

```
var converted = data.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(c => new Count { TradersCount = c.Count,
                                             Id = c.Id,
                                             Description = c.Description });
```

You can *try* doing them all in one go:

```
var data = from tc in _db.tblTradersCategories
           group tc by new { tc.tblCategory.categoryId,
                             tc.tblCategory.description } into g
           select new Count { TradersCount = g.Count,()
                              Id = g.Key.categoryId,
                              Description = g.Key.description };
```

But I don't know if that will work. It depends on how the LINQ provider handles it.

Comment: Surely class Count's properties are as easily populated as the anonymous class's properties.  I do not agree on the need for AsEnumerable.

Comment: @David B: The problem is that I don't know how the LINQ provider in question will handle attempts to create a non-anonymous, non-entity type. Will edit that into the answer.